# R get data.frame name in the function

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I wrote a function which does analysis with data.frame. 
In the function start, I print information what variables are taken in the function.
So I want to print info of data.frame name which is used.

But I can not get data.frame name printed. It does not print the data.frame name, instead it prints its content, but not name. 
is it possible to print the name of data.frame which is passed to function internally in the function.

```
tmpFuction <- function(DF){

print("#############")
print("tmpFuction starts")
print(paste("DF",DF,sep="="))
print("#############")
return(1)
}
df1 <- data_frame(id=seq(1:4),x=rep(0,4))
df2 <- data_frame(id=c(1,2),x=c(0,4))
tmpFuction(10)
tmpFuction("a")
tmpFuction(df1)
tmpFuction(df2)
```

The output. For the last 2 examples I want to be printed:

```
[1] "#############"
[1] "tmpFuction starts"
```

> ```
> [1] "DF=df1"
> ```

```
[1] "#############"

[1] "#############"
[1] "tmpFuction starts"
```

> ```
> [1] "DF=df2"
> ```

```
[1] "#############"
[1] 1
>
```

But I get:

```
> tmpFuction(10)
[1] "#############"
[1] "tmpFuction starts"
[1] "DF=10"
[1] "#############"
[1] 1
> tmpFuction("a")
[1] "#############"
[1] "tmpFuction starts"
[1] "DF=a"
[1] "#############"
[1] 1
> tmpFuction(df1)
[1] "#############"
[1] "tmpFuction starts"
[1] "DF=1:4"           "DF=c(0, 0, 0, 0)"
[1] "#############"
[1] 1
> tmpFuction(df2)
[1] "#############"
[1] "tmpFuction starts"
[1] "DF=c(1, 2)" "DF=c(0, 4)"
[1] "#############"
[1] 1
>
```

Comment: deparse(substitute returns you the name of a variable, you could call it like this in your function:
`DF <- data.frame(c(1,2));
print(paste("DF", deparse(substitute(DF)),sep="="))`

Comment: I also found a solution when passing not a data.frame as a function variable, but passing a data.frame name as a string and then use get function.
       dfString <- data_frame(id=c(1,2),x=c(0,4)); 
       df <- get('dfString')

Comment: Should work too, however in your attempt you should provide the get function with the environment where your data.frame is defined, otherwise you might end up with strange misbehaviour as a different data frame of the same name could be used. Hence my suggestion should be "safer" do you want me to provide it as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

deparse(substitute()) 
returns you the name of a variable, you can call it like this in your function:

```
DF <- data.frame(c(1,2)); print(paste("DF", deparse(substitute(DF)),sep="="))
```